# Receiving and handling no connect error and 200 OK header

Tags: php, ajax, json, api, error-handling

I'm working with an API which I've created myself, which I'm communicating with, with my code below. The API returns json if everything works as it should, as well as the header '200 OK'. If however the connection is broken I return '502 Bad Gateway' as header.

So far 'CURLOPT_HEADER' has been set to false in my php script (se below), but now I've set it to true so that I can receive the headers and take actions depending on the header. Here I need help.

#### I actually have two things I need help with (which are connected to each other):

1. If the connection is working between my API and the sources and I set CURLOPT_HEADER to false in my php script (se below) everything works as supposed. However, if I turn it to true the actual header is sent back with the ajax request as well, which returns in an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H" (line 10 in the js code below).
2. I don't have a clue on how to handle the error, if the connection is down between my API and the sources, and the API therefore returns '502 Bad Gateway'. I want the php script to send that information back with the ajax request, so it can be handled in the js file.

So, please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

**PHP:**

```
$url = 'http://theurl.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$response) {
    // <--- ??
}

curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode($response);
```

**JS:**

```
1.    $.ajax({
2.        url:'./php/apihandling.php',
3.        type:'post',
4.        dataType:'json',
5.            data:{ 
6.            data: data
7.       },
8.       success: function(data) {
9.           var content = JSON.parse(data);
10.          console.log(content);
11.       },
12.      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
13.          console.log(xhr.status);
14.          console.log(thrownError);
15.      }
16.  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use to curl_errno check how your API responds to your request, you can also try to use a API "status flag" to avoid errors in your JQuery

```
...
// Check if any error occurred
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 //close the connection
 curl_close($ch);
 $result["API_status"]=0;
 $result["error"]=$info;
 //kill the script and echo the json
 die(json_encode($result));
} 
else
{
$result["API_status"]=1;
curl_close($ch);
$result["response"]=$response;
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now let's give a try to your jquery script

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/apihandling.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        data: data
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //no need for this, datatype is json already   
        //var content = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data["API_status"]) {
            alert("wow API is up and healthy");
            //do some stuff with the json
            $.each(data["response"], function(index, value) {
                //loop this
            });
        } else {
            alert("Oh, no. RIP API");
            console.log(data["error"]);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, it's not working correctly when I try it out. Even if the data is successfully retrieved from the API, $result["API_status"] is set to 0. When I console.log out the data in the js script it contains of the correct data, even though API_status was set to 0. I have copy/pasted my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmwyt/ ... if you want to have a look... to see if I've done something wrong. Thanks again!